# why is it necessary for an order of abelian group to be a square free number only?

Tags: group-theory

For instance consider the group $G = \{1 , -1 , i, -i\}$ , it is a cyclic group of order 4 and it is abelian as well but 4 is not a square free number so how does the above theorem holds true ?

Comment: Where did you find this "theorem"? For any number $n$, the cyclic group on $n$ elements is abelian

Comment: What makes you think that this is a theorem?  You have one counterexample already, the cyclic group of order $n^2$ is a whole family.

Answer (score 9):

I think you're confusing this statement with its converse. See this question: [Square free finite abelian group is cyclic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67143/square-free-finite-abelian-group-is-cyclic)

What is true is the following:

> If an abelian group has squarefree order, then it is cyclic.

See the linked question for a proof.