# let $~G~$ be a finite abelian group and $~a,~b∈G~,$ with order$(a)=m$ and order$(b) =n$. Which of the following are necessarily true?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

let  $~G~$ be  a finite abelian group and $~a,~b∈G~,$ with order$(a)=m$ and order$(b) =n$. Which of the following are necessarily true ?

1. order$(ab) = mn$
2. order$(ab) = \mathrm{lcm}(m,n)$
3. there is an element of $G$ whose order is $\mathrm{lcm}(m,n)$
4. order$(ab) = \gcd(m,n)$

I think $1$ and $3$ is correct answer. Is it correct ? or not correct? 
I  need only verification or some hints

Comment: See if this helps you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78544/if-orda-m-ordb-n-then-does-there-exist-c-such-that-ord-c-lcmm-n

Comment: @ Rohan  opt 3  is correct or not

Comment: Some counterexamples for the other parts can be based on choosing $b=a$ or $b=a^{-1}$.

Comment: thanks @ hardmath,,,pliz  tell  my another  question post also

Answer (score 0):

Here only **option** $\bf(3)$ is correct.

**Explanation:** Take $~G=\{1,-1\}~$ under multiplication. 
Let $~a=-1,~b=-1~.$ So $~\text{O}(a)=2=m~$(say) and $~\text{O}(b)=2=n~$(say).
Then $~ab=(-1)\cdot(-1)=1\implies \text{O}(ab)=1~,$
which is not equal to $~mn~$ or $~\gcd(m,n)~$ or $~\mathrm{lcm}(m,n)~.$
Hence options $(1),~(2)$ and $(4)$ are not true.