# Power of commutator formula

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups, p-groups

A few people remember a commutator formula of the form $[a,b]^n = (a^{-1} b^{-1})^n (ab)^n c$ where $c$ is a product of only a few commutators (say $n-1$) of them.  Here $a,b$ are in a (free) group and $[a,b] := a^{-1} b^{-1} a b$.

Does anyone remember such a formula with proof?

Some such formula must exist where $c$ is in the commutator subgroup of $\langle a,b\rangle$, but my recollection is that $c$ is a product of something more like $n^2$ commutators.

Answers that only work for $n=2$ are less interesting to me. There should be a radical difference for $n \geq 3$.

Comment: I believe the formula people were thinking of is: $(xy)^m=x^my^m[y, x]^{m/2}$. This holds in a $2$-step nilpotent group, so is in your "uninteresting" category. See p141 of Robinson, A Course in the Theory of Groups. However, I am sure that there is a similar formula used in Leedham-Green and MacKay's book on $p$-groups which they use in the chapter on $p$-groups of maximal class. Thus, nilpotency class more than $2$...

Comment: $m/2$ is actually the binomial coefficient $m$ choose 2, though

Comment: @MathsLover: sounds good, put it the proof in the answer box. :-)

Comment: Or check Gorenstien "Finite Groups" Harper an Row, chapter 5

Comment: Two long shots: Marshall Hall's book on group theory has a section on free groups, and you could also try Philip Hall's papers on free groups

Comment: To be clear, I would consider myself extremely familiar with the books referenced. They all give quadratic growth modulo a term of the lower central series.

Comment: I did finding “Cullen's” formula for $n=3$ new and deeply disturbing. Thanks @exitingcorpse. :-)

Comment: For a formula of a similar shape (and other relevant discussion I'm sure), check out Danny Calegari's book on stable commutator length. The formula I'm looking at is on page 15, and it cites a paper of Cullen. the link is http://math.uchicago.edu/~dannyc/scl/toc.html . i've converted this to a comment because i feel it's more appropriate that way

Comment: @JackSchmidt , i think my formula is not accurate-so i deleted the comment- ! i meant this formula , $(xy)^n = x^ny^n[y,x]^{n(n-1)/2}$ and of course we can translate it to a formula for [x,y] using inverses . if this is useful, a proof for this formula is here http://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/06/20/a-fact-regarding-the-interaction-of-powers-and-commutators-in-a-group/ .

Comment: Cool. I added some variations on these from the books mentioned.

Comment: @exitingcorpse: i'd be interested in knowing the commutator length of $(ab)^3 b^{-3} a^{-3}$ in the free group on $a,b$. It is at most 14. I am trying to get lower bounds now (by working in finite quotients and using character theory).

Comment: (haha, and giving up on the char theory approach)

Comment: @JackSchmidt i believe there are algorithms to compute the commutator length in $F_2$ (and i know there is a package called 'scallop' that computes stable commutator length).

Comment: If anyone is curious, I wrote up some of the ideas in a pdf, now linked in the answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Positive results** are fairly nice. I [explain them in this note](http://www.ms.uky.edu/~jack/2013-06-21-Commutator.pdf) for commutators of powers (see the last pages for pretty pictures and crazy formulas). I didn't get around to the special case of powers of commutators, but Culler and Bavard give definitive results.

*Negative results:* These are just well known true formulas that have “$c$” being way too long, even allowing ourselves to omit longer commutators. If you've never done it, try to write $(ab)^3 = a^3 b^3 c$ and actually get a formula for $c$ only involving commutators (of commutators) of $a$ and $b$.

- Robinson, page 137, 5.3.5, $(xy)^m = x^m y^m [y,x]^{\binom{m}{2}} \mod \gamma_3$ has $c$ of quadratic length
- Hall, Chapters 11 and 12. I don't actually see the formula (!) but the algorithms used to derive the formula and their $\mod \gamma_4$ brethren are there, as well as the application to regular $p$-groups, which says that you can at least choose $c$ to be a product of $n$th powers, but no bound on how many. This is mod a more difficult to describe subgroup, as well.
- Gorenstein, Chapter 5.6 has the technique (again modulo a hard to describe subgroup, due to the $p$ versus $c$ of $\gamma_c$ relation). It also has applications of the formula in 5.3.9, but not the formula proper.
- Leedham-Green–McKay, Corollary 1.1.7
  $$[x,y]^n = (x^{-1} y^{-1})^n (xy)^n [y,x]^{\binom{n}{2}} [[y,x],x]^{\binom{n}{3}} \cdots$$
  $$[y,x]^n = [y^n,x] [[x,y],y]^{\binom{n}{2}} [[[x,y],y],y]^{\binom{n}{3}} \cdots$$
  modulo the subgroup generated by commutators containing at least 2 $x$s. Again quadratic (cubic, quartic, etc. if don't mod out by $\gamma_3$) not linear.
- Culler's formula is $$[a,b]^3 = [b^a,a^{-1} b^a b^{-1}][bab^{-1},b^2]$$ express a product of three commutators as a product of two commutators, which is disturbing. In fact Culler showed that the commutator length of $[a,b]^n$ is less than or equal to $\tfrac{n}{2} + 1$, and Bavard showed one has equality (with the greatest integer less than or equal to $\tfrac{n}{2}+1$). Danny Calegari and Alden Walker have improved the algorithms used in these papers while using the same basic topological idea. I would also mention the diagrams used in these works are on the inside covers of Rotman's group theory textbook.

  - Culler, Marc.
    “Using surfaces to solve equations in free groups.”
    Topology 20 (1981), no. 2, 133–145.
    MR[605653](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=605653)
    DOI:[10.1016/0040-9383(81)90033-1](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0040-9383(81)90033-1)
  - Bavard, Christophe.
    “Longueur stable des commutateurs.”
    Enseign. Math. (2) 37 (1991), no. 1-2, 109–150.
    MR[1115747](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1115747)
    DOI:[10.5169/seals-58734](http://dx.doi.org/10.5169/seals-58734)

### Two versus three

$n=2$ is special and has a finite formula with everything sorted:
$$(ab)^2 = abab = aab[b,a]b = a^2 b^2 [b,a] [[b,a],b]$$

$n=3$ is more like the rest, and has no finite formula if you try sort the commutators by weight. Even the unsorted formula is pretty long:
$$\begin{array}{ll}
(ab)^3 &= ababab \\
&= aab[b,a]bab \\
&= aab[b,a]ab[b,a]b \\
&= aaba[b,a][[b,a],a]b[b,a]b \\
&= aaab[b,a]^2[[b,a],a]b[b,a]b \\
&= a^3b[b,a]^2 b [[b,a],a] [[[b,a],a],b] [b,a] b \\
&= a^3b^2 [b,a][b,a,b][b,a][b,a,b][[b,a],a] [[[b,a],a],b] [b,a] b \\
&= a^3 b^3 [b,a][b,a,b][b,a,b][b,a,b,b][b,a][b,a,b][b,a,b] \\
&\quad [b,a,b,b][b,a,a][b,a,a,b][b,a,a,b][b,a,a,b,b][b,a][b,a,b]
\end{array}$$
Of course if we go mod $\gamma_4$ then we lose all that $[b,a,b,b]$ nonsense and are left with:
$$(ab)^3 = a^3 b^3 [b,a]^3 [b,a,b]^5 [b,a,a]^1 \mod \gamma_4$$

The powers on those commutators are called Hall polynomials if you let $n$ vary.

$$(ab)^n = a^n b^n [b,a]^{\binom{n}{2}} [b,a,a]^{\binom{n}{3}} [b,a,b]^{2\binom{n}{3}+\binom{n}{2}} \mod \gamma_4$$

has cubic growth. The Hall polynomial for $[b,a,a,\ldots,a]$ is always $\binom{n}{k}$. There are also three variable and higher versions.

### Commutator length

Actually, the commutator length may be much shorter than the formulas indicate.

$$(ab)^3 = a^3 b^3 [ {(ab)}^{-1} b^2, b^{-1} (ab)^2 ]$$
$$(ab)^3 = (ba)^3 [aba,bab]$$

The first can be applied with $a=x^{-1} y^{-1}$ and $b=xy$ to answer the main question.

Guided by [scallop](https://github.com/aldenwalker/scallop) by [Alden Walker](http://math.uchicago.edu/~akwalker/) and Danny Calegari, I found $$(ab)^4 = a^4 b^4 
 [a^{-1}b^2, a^{-2}ba][ ba^{-2}ba,(ba)^2b ]$$

I think these shorter formulas lose some of the theoretical importance that the “nicer” formulas had, but I worry this sort thing will give a positive answer to the question. I continue to be interested in a positive answer.

### Positive result

To prove Schur's theorem that if $[G:Z(G)]$ is finite then so is $G'$, Ornstein showed this in a way very similar to Cullen's formula and the commutator length ideas. The first step was the remembered claim $[a,b]^n = (ba)^{-n} (ab)^n u$ where $u$ is a product of $n-1$ commutators. This follows from induction on $n$ with $n=1$ being clear. $$\begin{array}{ll}
[a,b]^n
&= [a,b] [a,b]^{n-1} \\
&= [a,b] (ba)^{1-n} (ab)^{n-1} u_{n-2} \\
&= (ba)^{-1}(ab) (ba)^{1-n} (ab)^{n-1} u_{n-2} \\
&= (ba)^{-1}(ba)^{1-n} (ab)^{n-1} (ab) [ (ab), (ba)^{1-n} (ab)^{n-1} ] u_{n-2} \\
&= (ba)^{-n} (ab)^n u_{n-1}
\end{array}$$

Thanks to Babak for finding this simple proof. This is used with $n=[G:Z(G)]$ since then $(ba)^{-n} (ab)^n = 1$ because $(ab)^n \in Z(G)$ and $(ab)^n = ((ba)^b)^n = ((ba)^n)^b = (ba)^n$. This gives that $[a,b]^n$ is a product of $n-1$ commutators, rather than $n$. In any product of commutators of minimal length, no commutator appears to a power higher than $n$. Since $xyx = x^2 y^x$ and the commutator length of a conjugate is the same as the original, we can sort any such expression to bring all copies of a commutator into a power. Hence no commutator appears anywhere in a minimal expression $n$ or more times. Since there are only at most $n^2$ commutators, that is a total of less than $n^3$ expressions, so $|G'| \leq [G:Z(G)]^3$. I suspect the other formulas we have give that $|G'| \leq 3[G:Z(G)]^2$.

Comment: +10. Very nice Jack. I have searched for you to find the result I mentioned yesterday. I hope you are to upset cause of me but I want to be sure of it, not just posting an answer. See please Rotman's book. Page 114, Theorem 5.32( Schur). As I thought last night, he assumed there $G/Z$ is finite. Sorry again. I am one one of your fan. :-)

Comment: @BabakS. thanks, this has been very educational. I haven't had a chance to read about strengthening of Schur's inequality, but I suspect I'll now understand them!

Comment: I am not sure how related this is to your actual aims, but I miss the paper in your long list: Bavard improved on Culler's results in [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.5169/seals-58734). He shows that $[a,b]^n$ can be written as a product of $\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor + 1$ commutators and shows that this is actually best possible. He gives an explicit formula in section 1.4.

Comment: @Martin thanks! That is very similar to the original question, which asks about $(ab)^{-n} (ba)^n [a,b]^n$. I think $[a,b]^n$ by itself is probably a more natural thing to want to know about. :-) Culler, Bravard, and Calegari all appear to be using the same basic technique that apparently I ought to learn.

Comment: I should have mentioned this in my previous comment: much of Bavard's paper (only one r, by the way :-)) can be found in chapter 2 of Calegari's recent *scl* monograph.

Comment: Thanks. I suspect I'll need to rewrite this answer after I read *scl*.

Comment: Dear Jack, what is the original reference for the proof of Schur's theorem by Ornstein (in last section of your answer)? I mean, what is the journal/book, where the proof of Ornstein appeared first? One author mentions about it in the book "Intr. to Differential Algebra", publ. around 1959.