# Subgroup of $\left(GL_2\left(R\right),\:\cdot \right)$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Is $t\left(GL_2\left(\mathbb{R}\right)\right)=\left\{x\in GL_2\left(\mathbb{R}\right)|\:ord\left(x\right)\:<\:\infty \right\}$ a subgroup of $\left(GL_2\left(\mathbb{R}\right),\:\cdot \right)$ ? Justify your answer.

$GL_2\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ is the general linear group, meaning it's the group of 2 x 2 invertible matrices of real numbers.

How do I solve this problem? I'm really new to group theory.

Comment: @quid Ah yes, of course, I am sorry. This [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41303/examples-and-further-results-about-the-order-of-the-product-of-two-elements-in-a) is better, I hope. The answer of "amWhy" includes the one of Omnomnomnom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer here is going to be no.  For example, consider the product 
$$
\pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1} \pmatrix{1&1\\0&-1} = \pmatrix{1&1\\0&1}
$$
can you see how this "counterexample" shows that the set *fails to be a subgroup*?

As for "how to solve it": my best advice is that if there isn't an obvious way to prove it, start by looking for a counterexample.  Either you find one, or you start to see why there aren't any.

Comment: So I basically needed to find two elements from $GL_2\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ which have an order that is less than infinite, but for which their product has an infinite order? Hence their product wont be part of $GL_2\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$, right?

Comment: It's not that their product won't be a part of $GL_2(\Bbb R)$ (of course they *will* be a part of $GL_2(\Bbb R)$ since $GL_2$ is a group).  It's that their product won't be a part of $t(GL_2)$ (which is probably what you meant anyway).

Comment: So yes: we had to find two matrices of finite order whose product has infinite order.  In so doing, we show that $t(GL_2)$ *fails* to be a subgroup.

Comment: Yup, that's what I meant. Thank you for your time :)