# Can we create, for any two given natural numbers $m,n$ , a group $G$ having two elements $a,b$ with $|a|=m, |b|=n$ and $|ab|=\infty$

Tags: group-theory

> Written with [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/).

> Can we create, for any two given natural numbers $m,n$ , a group $G$ having two elements $a,b$ with $|a|=m,|b|=n$ and $|ab|=\infty$

Through an exercise in Gallian, I learnt that we can do this in **General Linear Group of 2x2 matrices**(Feel free to ask for pictures in comments) for elements of order 3 and 4.

Extending this with a basic application of external direct products(With multiplicative group of complex numbers, for instance) , we can create elements of orders $3k_1$ and $4k_2$ $\forall k_1,k_2 \in \Bbb N  $ which give their product to have infinite order.

But can this be generalized, for all pairs of natural numbers?

Comment: I believe this tread contains valuable information http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41303/examples-and-further-results-about-the-order-of-the-product-of-two-elements-in-a

Comment: Your question, as currently phrased does not make sense, but the answer to the question you intended to ask is yes.

Comment: @DerekHolt- I got my answer, I couldn't understand how my question was vague(Despite so many people being confused), could you suggest adjustments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - we can build such a group via [generators and relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group).

Specifically, the simplest such group is $$G=\langle a, b: a^m=b^n=e\rangle.$$ This is the [free group on two generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group), modulo the normal subgroup generated by $a^m$ and $b^n$; it's easy to check that $a$ has order $m$, $b$ has order $n$, but $ab$ has infinite order.

---

Here's a concrete description of $G$. An element of the free group on two generators is an equivalence class of *words* in $\{a, b, a^{-1}, b^{-1}\}$; the equivalence relation is, "can be gotten from each other by adding/removing strings of the form "$aa^{-1}$," "$a^{-1}a$", "$bb^{-1}$," and "$b^{-1}b$". For example, $$\mbox{"$abaa$," "$abaa^{-1}b^{-1}baa$," and $"abaabb^{1}$"}$$ each represent the same element.

The quotient group $G$ is defined the same way, but we have a broader class of "deletable/addable" strings: namely, in addition to the four above, we also have "$a^m$" and "$b^n$".

Answer (score 1):

There are groups in which for all pairs of natural numbers $m,n>1$ there are elements of orders $m$ and $n$ with product of infinite order.

E.g. in the group of permutations of $\mathbb{N}$ take, for any $m,n>1$:

$g=(0, ... ,m-1)(m+n-2, ... ,2m+n-3)(2m+2n-4, ... ,3m+2n-5) ...$

and

$h=(m-1, ... ,m+n-2)(2m+n-3, ... ,2m+2n-4)$
$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (3m+2n-5, ... ,3m+3n-6) ...$

Then $g$ has order $m$, $h$ has order $n$ and $gh$ has infinite order.

Was that what you were asking?

P.S. By $gh$ here I mean first apply $g$, then apply $h$. Many people do this back to front. But whichever way, you still get an element of infinite order because $o(hg)=o(h^{-1}(hg)h)=o(gh)$. It's just more awkward to calculate.

Comment: Regarding Derek Holt's comment on the question and OP's subsequent query, I would say the question as posed is perfectly reasonable. It obviously needs to discount the cases $m\leq 1$ or $n\leq 1$ and to me it wasn't clear if the question was $$(\exists G)(\forall m,n\in \mathbb{N})(\exists g,h\in G)(o(g)=m\wedge o(h)=n\wedge o(gh)\ \textrm{is infinite})$$ or $$(\forall m,n\in \mathbb{N})(\exists G)(\exists g,h\in G)(o(g)=m\wedge o(h)=n\wedge o(gh)\ \textrm{is infinite})$$Hardly grounds for saying the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: In fact the above answer answers both and the subsequent answer answers the first but can be extended in an obvious way to also answer both.

Comment: (For "first" read "second" in the previous.)

Comment: @Lelouch - By the way if "despite so many people being confused" relates to my question, "Was that what you were asking?", I included the latter because you give no explicit  connection between the numbers $m$ and $n$ and the group elements mentioned. I assumed you meant that $m$ and $n$ were the orders of those elements.