# Order of group generated by two elements of finite Order

Tags: group-theory

If we have two matrices of finite Order and we generate a group from these two matrices, then is there any tool to find order of such group. Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes. There is nothing special about two. Given any finite set of matrices, there are algorithms to decide whether they generate a finite group and to calculate its order. But they are far too long and technical to be summarised here. You can attempt such calculations in GAP or Magma. Do you have a specific problem of this type?

Answer (score 0):

In general, the product of elements $a$ and $b$ of order $n$ respectively $m$ can be arbitrary, even infinite, see

[Examples and further results about the order of the product of two elements in a group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41303/examples-and-further-results-about-the-order-of-the-product-of-two-elements-in-a)

For information on subgroups of $GL(n,q)$ resp. $SL(n,q)$ with two generators see [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/158120/subgroups-of-general-linear-group-with-two-generators), and [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/212432/what-are-the-2-generated-subgroups-of-the-special-linear-group-sl2-q-over-a).

Comment: The question was about the order of the group generated by the two matrices, not the order of the product of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Yes, I know, but with this example of two matrices $A$, $B$ of finite order, giving a product matrix of infinite order, the order of the group $\langle A,B\rangle$ is infinite.

Comment: Yes that's true. And even if $AB$ has finite order, $\langle A,B \rangle$ might still be infinite.