# Why does this relationship between $|ab|$ and $|a||b|$ apply only in a finite group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation

From Joseph A. Galligan's *Contemporary Abstract Algebra (2nd ed.)*, we have the following corollary:

> **Corollary 3** (Relationship between $|ab|$ and $|a||b|$). If $a$ and $b$ belong to a finite group and $ab = ba$, then $|ab|$ divides $|a||b|$.

> *Proof*. Let $|a| = m$ and $|b| = n$. Then $(ab)^{mn} = (a^m)^n(b^n)^m = e^n e^m = e$. So, by Corollary 2 of Theorem 4.1 we have that $|ab|$ divides $mn$.

For reference, Corollary 2 says that $a^k = e$ implies $|a|$ divides $k$.

This proof makes sense in all areas except for one—each step in the proof seems valid to me regardless of whether the group $a$ and $b$ belong to is finite. Why does this group have to be finite? Where in the proof does it go wrong otherwise?

Comment: The result holds in any group (finite or infinite) in which $a$ and $b$ have finite order and commute. Because if the latter holds in $G$, then it also holds in $\langle a,b\rangle$ which is provably finite. The statement may reflect the assumptions from whatever theorem this is a corollary of, rather than its truth in other settings.

Comment: Some [counterexamples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41303/) if the elements don't have to commute.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Excuse me, but what does the does the notation $\langle a, b \rangle$ mean?

Comment: Subgroup generated by $a$ and $b$.